# What can cause a “non-unique matches detected” error in an r merge?

Tags: r, merge

I am trying to merge a spatial polygons data frame and a data frame, but I keep getting a “non-unique matches detected” error.  I have run duplicated() on the columns used for by.x and by.y and no duplicates are detected.  What else could cause this error?

```
> head(AnteNatal.df)
              Country Year(s) AnteNatalValue
1         Afghanistan    2011           14.6
2             Albania    2009           66.8
3              Angola    2009           47.1
4 Antigua and Barbuda    2011          100.0
5           Argentina    2006           24.7
6             Armenia    2010           92.8

> Africa.sh$NAME[1:5]
[1] Angola       Burundi      Benin        Burkina Faso Botswana    
243 Levels: Afghanistan Aland Albania Algeria American Samoa Andorra Angola        Anguilla Antarctica ... Zimbabwe
```

> 

The calls

```
duplicated(Africa.sh$NAME)
duplicated(AnteNatal.df$Country)
```

both return lists containing all FALSE.  However, when I try to merge, I get

```
> merge(Africa.sh,AnteNatal.df, by.x = "NAME", by.y ="Country")
Error in .local(x, y, ...) : non-unique matches detected
```

Comment: Can you show us the call to `merge` ?

Comment: and how did you use `duplicated`?

Answer (score 34):

Use the sp::merge function with the duplicateGeoms argument set to TRUE (if TRUE geometries in x are duplicated if there are multiple matches between records in x and y)

```
    require(sp)
    ?sp::merge
    merge(spatial_data, data_frame, by = 'match_column', duplicateGeoms = TRUE)
```

(I know this question is older, but I came across it while in search for an answer to it myself)

Comment: In you have different x and y names on the same column, specify this here: `sp::merge(spdf, df, duplicateGeoms = TRUE, by.x = "NAME", by.y ="Country")`

Answer (score 0):

I found this patch. You extract that data from your SP to data frame.

`final_merge <-  merge(sp_extract,final_merge, by.x = "name", by.y = "name2" ,all.x = TRUE )`

Then you merge to your SP and its should work

```
 sp_merge  <- sp::merge(sp, final_merge , by.x = "name" , by.y = "name", duplicateGeoms = TRUE,no.dups = FALSE )
```